# fstream.open() does not fail when it should c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I am writing a piece of code that is supposed to convert a txt file to an xml file and vice versa.

After taking in a path for existing txt file from user,  I take the path to create an xml file from the user. And then for example I type in `"blablabla"` as the xml path and the stream always opens, and `good()` method always returns true.

No matter what I type in as path for the non existent file, stream always open despite the file not being created. How do I make the code fail with improper path?

Heres my code:

main.cpp

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1 : {
        //initialize a converter
        Converter toXmlConverter = Converter();

        //set txt input path for converter
        cout << "input txt file path: " ;
        string txtPathStr;
        cin >> txtPathStr;
        const char *path = txtPathStr.c_str();

        if (!fileExistsCheck(path)) {
            cout << "file does not exist" << endl;
            break;
        }
        toXmlConverter.setNewTxtFilePath(path);


        //set xml output path for converter
        cout << "output xml file path: " ;
        string xmlPathStr;
        cin >> xmlPathStr;
        const char *xmlPath = xmlPathStr.c_str();
        toXmlConverter.setNewXmlFilePath(xmlPath);

        //perform the conversion, return true if conversion successful, false if not

        if(!toXmlConverter.convertTxtToXml()) { <-----THIS SHOULD RETURN FALSE!!!!
            cout << "bad xml output path" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "success" << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
```

And this is the convertTxtToXml() method from the Converter class

```
bool Converter::convertTxtToXml() {

    // declaring input, output files
    fstream plikTxt;
    fstream plikXml;

    plikTxt.open(newTxtFilePath, ios::in);
    plikXml.open(newXmlFilePath, ios::out);
    //checking if open/create was successful
    if (plikXml.is_open()) { <--------SHOULD RETURN FALSE WITH A BOGUS PATH
        return false;
    }

    //variable to hold currently read line
    string readLine;

    //adding xml header to plikXml
    plikXml << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" << endl << "<root>" << endl;

    //looping while there are lines to read
    while (getline(plikTxt, readLine)) {

        //add <row> node for each line read
        plikXml << "<row>" << endl;

        //split read line into separate words with whitespace as a separator
        istringstream buf(readLine);
        istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;
        vector<string> tokens(beg, end);

        //add a column node for each of the read elements, after splitting line
        for (auto& s: tokens) {
            plikXml << "<col>" << s << "</col>" << endl;
        }

        //close the <row> node after processing line
        plikXml << "</row>" << endl;
    }
    //closing <root> node after looping through all lines
    plikXml << "</root>";

    plikTxt.close();
    plikXml.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: As of C++11, there is no need for the likes of `const char *path = txtPathStr.c_str();`.  `fstream` handles `std::string` just fine.

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't created?

Comment: Recommendation: Back up your code, then throw most of it out. If you are having problems figuring out why you can open file you shouldn't be able to open, you should focus on the code that opens the files. The rest is noise. A test program for this should be around 10 lines. For more on this concept, read [mcve]

Comment: In the realm of unsolicited advice, that `case` statement is **way** too long. All of that code should go in a function, so that it's easy to see what the various cases are and what they do, without having to scroll through pages of code.

Comment: `if ( /*==> */  ! /* <==*/   plikXml.is_open()) { return false; }` hint: note the `!` !

Comment: @NathanOliver well, im sure I can not find it anywhere. @ Everyone else, I know this code is completely not clean, actully its the first thing I have ever done in c++ so first I want to get it working. But thanks for all the comments :)

Comment: @gap210 You want to return `false` if the file could \*not\* be opened? Could be opened: `plikXml.is_open() == true` ... could \*not\* be opened: `!plikXml.is_open() == true`

Comment: gap, getting it working is why Pete Becker's advice is so important. If you make a program built up from many different and simple things you can write and test each of these little things separately, and since they are all simple, the tests are also simple. When you have to write and test a large, tightly coupled program it is much harder to test as you go, the program must be complete enough to test, and the tests become much more complex because of the larger number of possible code paths that must all be tested together.

Comment: You should also consider making `convertTxtToXml()` return false if it can't open both files: `plikTxt.open(...); if (!plikTxt.is_open()) return false; plikXml.open(...); if (!plikXml.is_open()) return false` or `plikTxt.open(...); plikXml.open(...); if (!(plikTxt.is_open() && plikXml.is_open())) return false;` Either way, you don't need `fileExistsCheck()`, that just introduces a race condition (the file could be deleted after you check it but before you open it) and a possible false-positive result (depending on how you are performing the check). Just let `open()` fail if it needs to.

Comment: @J.Doe I think I was too quick to call victory - so after removing !   , plikXml.is_open() ALWAYS returns true, even if path is wrong, so my "if" ALWAYS returns false, even if the path is good. I simply dont understand why calling plikXml.open("notAValidPath", ios::out) results in true from .is_open every time

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point with the fileExistsCheck. My problem is that I cant get open() to fail with anything but nullpointer in path

Comment: @gap210 I guess you haven't read `fstream`'s documentation yet. When opening a file for **output**, `open()` will *create* the file if it does not already exist. So why exactly are you expecting it to fail on a path to a non-existent file? BTW, you should typically use `std::ifstream` for input and `std::ofstream` for output, there is very little use for using `std::fstream` unless you need to open a file for BOTH input AND output, which is rare.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy for the reply. All I want to do is, when a bogus path is provided, like "fffff", i want the is_open() to return false. Is that possible? Or even with such a path the file is opened somewhere in memory, only not to be saved under the bogus path later? If so how can I verify if the path is valid?

Comment: @gap210 If you `std::ifstream plikTxt{ "your_filename_that_doesn't_exist" }; if(!plikTxt.is_open()) std::cerr << "yay, it works!!";` and don't get the output "yay, it works!!" then - sorry - your standard library implementation is broken.

Comment: @J.Doe the issue is with `plikXml` for output, not `plikTxt` for input.

Comment: @gap210 what do you consider to be "bogus" exactly? `"fffff"` is a valid filename. `open()` will happily create a new file of that name when using `std::ios::out` if the file does not exist yet. Read the documentation for [`std::basic_filebuf::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), it shows various combination of flags and what affect they have on the file